# How do I force a user to a wait page after clicking hyperlink to download a file?

Tags: redirect, hyperlink, download, web

Is there any way that every user must wait before clicking on a direct link. For example, they click on a link to `mysite.com/downloads/file.zip`. With no modification, `file.zip` will start downloading. I want to redirect users to a wait time page. I want this to apply to every file inside a folder, but not other parts of the website.

For example, I want all files inside `public_html/directory/downloads` to have wait time, but I don't want this to affect other files in `public_html/directory` or `public_html/`.

Comment: I edited the title to make it more descriptive of the question you have in the body - don't forget that's the first thing that people will see.  I also re-formatted the body a little, putting the literal text in inline code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it with with three files, and the download file. Copy and paste next code in three files (Z.HTML, ZZ.HTML AND ZZZ.HTML), and you will need the download file (ZZZZ.CMAP).

Z.HTML :

> ```
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <title>Redirect</title>
>   </head>
>   <body style="background-color:cyan;">
>     <a href="zz.html">Click here to download file</a>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

ZZ.HTML :

> ```
> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=zzz.html" />
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <title>Waiting</title>
>   </head>
>   <body style="background-color:pink;">
>     Wait 5 seconds before download the file (in the meantime, enjoy our publicity)
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

ZZZ.HTML :

> ```
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <title>Downloading</title>
>     <script type="text/javascript">
> setTimeout( "window.location='zzzz.cmap'",1000 );
>     </script>
>   </head>
>   <body style="background-color:yellow;">
>     Downloading
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

Once you have the three files, double click Z.HTML to start the process.

Comment: I dont get it, this doesnt affect whole folder specified. It affects only 1 file

Comment: Try adding one setTimeout for every single file. For the whole folder you will have to read the folder content, for example, with PHP : http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Comment: Ye, but files in /downloads/ folder/directory will be automatically uploaded, and with your method you have to add files manually and click in z.html file. I want this: when users click in mysite.com/downloads/file.zip they will be redirected to a wait page

Comment: I showed you how to do it with one file, now Klajdi Him will do it for many files, for example, using PHP. Anyway, do you want all files to start downloading one after another?

Comment: Lets get straight to it. I am providing a free service, similar to mirror, "downloads" folder of my website will be used to store lots of files and data, hundrets,thousands or millions of files. It is impossible to add them 1 by one. and users will click on direct link, not in z.html link. Although your method is useful, it is not what I want.

Comment: If your website will have millions of files, how will people choose the file or files they want to download? They will have to do it one by one, with links on screen and clicking on them.

Comment: They will search for a specific file, and in results, there will be file they want along with direct link to download. If you want I can give you a sample.

Comment: After the search, you will use my three files to redirect, wait and download the file.

Comment: I dont have access to search page, only to mirrors. I provide details to site, when publishers submits files, files gets uploaded in multiple mirrors, when a user searchs for a specific file, and he finds it, there will be my mirror.

Comment: Klajdi, if your website gets the file link, you can add this link to the third file (ZZZ.HTML) to download it, after the waiting page and your publicity. Why do you think you can't do it?

Comment: this should answer your question. editing file names will create broken mirrors http://i.snag.gy/zOhPD.jpg

Comment: Don't edit anything, just add the link to the third file : setTimeout( "window.location='YOUR-LINK'",1000 ); . I guess your website will get the link dynamically, for example, using PHP, well, you can use PHP to replace the YOUR-LINK part dynamically for any link your website gets.

Comment: this is what i have in zzz.html           <html>
  <head>
    <title>Downloading</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout( "window.location='www.mysite.com/downloads'",1000 );
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:yellow;">
    Downloading
  </body>
</html>                                                                                                                        and when i click on www.mysite.com/downloads/download.zip , file starts downloading with no wait time.

Comment: You have to start with Z.HTML, making users believe they will download the file they want, but they will be redirected to ZZ.HTML where Klajdi will show publicity and make some money, after a few seconds, user will be automatically sent to ZZZ.HTML where the real download will start (where YOUR-LINK is). By the way, you have to use a filename as link, not a folder name, because if you use a folder name the browser will show a long directory list.

Comment: I get it, but what i dont get is, where should I post z.html, and how will it redirect peoples in file they wanted, when in 3rd file is only 1 link

Comment: You told me your webiste gets a link from an unknown search service. Right after that your website will show Z.HTML, and the cycle begins. To pass the link page after page, you will have to store it somewhere, for example, using PHP session, this way you will be able to paste the link in ZZZ.HTML, like this setTimeout( "window.location='<?php echo $_SESSION['my_link'];?>",1000 );.

Comment: How can it show z.html when users will click in direct link?

Comment: You will not show users the direct link, you will show Z.HTML. The direct link will be used until users reach ZZZ.HTML. Wouldn't you like to mark my answer as the right one? I would really apreciate it.

Comment: And how does it finds out which file has user requested to download. If i provide mysite.com/downlaods/z.html as http path, how will it know which file users searched for?

Comment: Klajdi said there is a search service that finds files. Klajdi's website will get the filename or link from there (I guess).

Comment: Klajdi can also create his own search page, once the user finds a filename, you store it in SESSION and call Z.HTML to start the download process.

Comment: you are saying to put www.mysite.com/downloads/z.html in http directory field? This field is used from other website to upload file in my ftp, and in same time is used to give direct link, i cant put a file direction in it.

Comment: Can it be possible to redirect users from mysite.com/downloads/download.zip to a wait time page. I heard that, for ex. If a user uploads sample.zip , it will be stored in mysite.com/downloads/category1/sample.zip (uploaded automatically) it will also create a directory sample.zip in the same direction with file sample.zip. My server automatically detects uploaded file, create directory, and inside sample.zip directory create z.html,zz.html,zzz.html where in 3rd file it will set filename by getting it in the direct link that user clicked in the begining.

Comment: That would be great, because everything would be automatic (the server working for you). You can also create your own search page, to allow users to search files in your website or database, and if any file matches, you call Z.HTML and add the file to ZZZ.HTML.

Comment: yes, it is a good idea, but how, i dont have any php or html knowledge. And i cant create my own search engine, as it will require a lot of work to get users and views, to make it popular.

Comment: In that case, use your own approach : create a copy of the 3 files (they are very small) in the directory every time a file is uploaded. (So, was my answer right or helpful?, do I deserve the points?)

Comment: but this is manual. I want it to be automatic. I want server to automatically create directory download.zip, automatically copy files and automatically replace name in 3rd file and automatically determine if user has clicked link (so users wont be redirected to folder again)

Comment: I think there are two ways : 
1. Program the upload service to create the 3 files automatically (we would need to see how files are uploaded). 
2. Program the search page to call the 3 files on every search (with PHP).

Comment: well, as i said i have access only to my ftp, and things that are in image i sent u before. How can we make program?

Comment: We are talking about building a whole website, with a database layer, a business layer, and an interface layer. It's a hard job, let's see : every uploaded file would activate our website from FTP (not sure how, maybe a web service), we would save in database the filename and link, we also have a search page for the user, this one calls a search script page, another page to show results, and our 3-Z pages. Not too much, just a few days of hard job.

Comment: well, you somehow answered my question. I think ill ask a question on how to make a simpler program. For now this is solved, thank you and you deserve to choose this answer as the best. :D